# JSP image couldn't be loaded

Tags: jsp

I have tried to put absolute path in jsp tag. But it doesn't display the image.

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="<c:url value='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/default-
    user-image.png'/>" alt="userImage" />
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

JSTL `<c:url>` tag has the `context` attribute ( optional) and it is set the current application as the context by default.

So, you can use like this without `contextPath`:

```
<c:url value='/images/default-user-image.png'/>
```

Secondly, To serve static resources with Spring, check your static handlers whether it works correctly or not.

For your example, add the following mapping in XML might work.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
```

Comment: thank you for your help. The problem was that I didn't add mapping in XML.

Comment: @HyunJung you're welcome. If you accept-upvote my answer I would be happy:)