# Include CSS in JSP page of Dynamic Web Application

Tags: css, jsp, spring-mvc, web-inf

My JSP pages in my dynamic web application (in Eclipse) are not being styled by my CSS code. I have included a stylesheet in index.jsp as follows:

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To Do List - Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="tasks">Tasks</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my project structure is as follows:

[image]

I thought that `href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/stylesheet.css` would look for `stylesheet.css` in `ToDoList/WebContent/css/`. If I try navigating directly to the stylesheet in the browser via `http://localhost:8080/ToDoList/css/stylesheet.css` it returns a 404 error.

I am aware this question has been asked before but from looking at the other questions I still can't figure out what is wrong with my project structure.

**Update:**

So I added `<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />` to my servlet config, but now when I navigate to any page other than index.jsp I get a 404 error.

**todolist-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Scan for JavaConfig, annotated with @Configuration -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.petehallw.todolist.main" />

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />

    <!-- Configure Spring view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The error I get is:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ToDoList/tasks] in DispatcherServlet with name 'todolist'
```

This is upon clicking a link to "tasks" in index.jsp which was previously returning the tasks.jsp page.

Comment: It looks like you need a static handler in todolist-servlet. Check out  [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863606/jsp-image-couldnt-be-loaded/43866534#43866534) . It might help.

Comment: Can you just drag and drop it from the tree into your project, and have it auto fill it for you?

Comment: @spas2k If I drag it in the value is "WebContent/css/stylesheet.css" and it doesn't work either.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt Thanks for the info, I tried your suggestion but I am now getting 404 error from my other pages. I have updated the question with the details.

Comment: Use c:url every url in the app.  <a href="<c:url value="/tasks"/>">Tasks</a>. If you have @requestmapping("/tasks") method, will be invoked. Or <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/tasks">Tasks</a> like you use at css files.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt Unfortunately still getting a 404 at `http://localhost:8080/ToDoList/tasks`..

Comment: which the package you put the controller class?

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt It's in `Java Resources --> src --> com.petehallw.todolist.main`

Comment: remove index.jsp or move it into /jsp folder like others. and to access index.jsp, add requestmapping("/") ... return "index";

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt I added that request mapping in a new controller `MainController` and modified my servlet config. Unfortunately now I get a 404 trying to access index.jsp. Would you mind taking a look at my code here please? https://gitlab.com/petehallw/to-do-list 
Really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: please, add todolist-servlet.xml <mvc:annotation-driven />. it is required for annotation like RequestMapping, Controller

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt That fixed it! Now I am able to see my JSP views and the CSS styling. Thank you very much!

Comment: you're welcome. if you accept my answers and upvote, I would be happy:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every URL in the app, you can make use of  `c:url` tag in `JSTL` lib.

```
<a href="<c:url value="/tasks"/>">Tasks</a>.
```

So, if you have controller method mapping  @requestmapping("/tasks"), it will be invoked.

Or try as `<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/tasks">Tasks</a>` like you use at css files.

**Important:** You should add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in xml configuration for the support of annotation-driven MVC controllers like `@RequestMapping`, `@Controller`.

Comment: Just to note, I do need to use the `<c:url/>` tag when including static content in my JSP page but for the link to "/tasks" it seems I don't need it. I did move my index.jsp file into WEB-INF-->jsp with the rest of the JSP files and create a root controller with `RequestMapping("/")` though so maybe that is why I don't need to specify the context path.

Comment: @petehallw yeah, you're right. Relative URLs will work, too.